# How dangerous are magnets to common electronics?

Tags: design, electromagnetic

I'm working on a fun little personal project, an electronics knickknack I'm hoping to fiddle with, like a fidget spinner. I want to use reasonably-strong magnets in the design, capable of holding around 3 kg (6.6 lbs) against gravity. I'm worried these magnets might pose a danger to the types of electronics I have lying around, namely phones, speakers, laptops, etc.

To what degree do I have to be concerned about using magnets around common household electronics?

**Edit**

In response to a very reasonable request from Mattman944 for the strength of the magnets I'm looking for, something around 0.2 tesla, two of them each on the left and right of this device. It seems there's no easy way I can share with you the design of the device, so I'll describe the magnets and their placement. The magnets would be encased in around 2 mm of PLA plastic, and would be separated from each other by about 1 cm of space. The goal is for the magnets to not pose a danger to typical consumer electronics I (or anyone else) am likely to have lying around. To be specific, I'm concerned about speakers, laptops, cellphones, and monitors, but I'd also love to know about any other devices to which these knickknacks could cause particular harm.

If you've got any questions or concerns about this question, definitely feel free to comment. I'm a bit new around here, and I'm all ears for suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on what is inside them. Phones probably wouldn't be a problem unless it contains a magnetometer. Speakers are a problem for permanent magnet types. Computers could be an issue for magnetic media. It also depends on how close you get them to these things.

Comment: You can probably saturate most ferrite transformers and inductors with that thing if you get close enough. Keep it away from electronics.

Comment: Old CRT monitors and TV could suffer a permanent damage

Comment: Besides the issues with electronics, such a magnet could be a pinching hazard. If they come loose, small ones can be swallowed by children.

Comment: i fully agree with @hacktastical ... children can suffer life threatening injuries from multiple swallowed magnets ... one magnet is not really a problem, if it is small ... the danger occurs if a second magnet is swallowed ... the two magnets can come together with tissue in between, the tissue would have blood cut off by the pressure and it would die

Comment: Purely electronic devices are rarely damaged by magnetic fields. One exception is Magneto Resistive Memory, but this is not used in household devices. Electromechanical devices such as speakers could be damaged if the magnet was large and very close. Your magnet is fairly small and probably not an issue. I got a 200 lb magnet close to my phone and the magnetometer was wacky for a while, but eventually recovered.

Comment: @Mattman944 That would be a great answer

Comment: Would someone mind letting me know why this question is being voted to close? I'm not sure how the question can be improved, and I haven't received a single comment to that effect.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but it could be improved if you can quantify your magnet better. Most phones have a magnetometer, but you probably need an app to get the values. I use "Teslameter 11" for iPhone, I don't know what is available for Android.

Comment: @Mattman944 Gotcha! I added some more details, please let me know if there's anything else I can do to be more specific! I'm a big fan of the community, so if there happens to be anything I could add, do let me know :)

Comment: Many laptops and ipads have magnet based switches used to trigger sleep states on closing the lid or case...

Comment: Found some info here; https://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/What-is-the-safe-distance-that-I-need-to-keep-to-my-devices